# Google Places Autocomplete to return non-abbreviated administrative areas?

Tags: google-places-api

Running the HTTP request: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=atlanta&types=(cities)&sensor=false&key=<api_key>`

returns results that include `Atlanta, GA, United States`

Is there a way to return results of a query that don't includes abbreviated names? So I could get back `Atlanta, Georgia, United States`?

Or do I need need to make an additional query with the reference token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Google Place Details API with the "reference" parameter returned by Google Place Auto Complete. This will return extensive information on your location query, including long and short names.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=x&key=y&sensor=false

where x is the "reference" from your auto complete query, and y = your API key.

Here is the link for the Details API:
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsRequests

Comment: It sucks I have to make one more query, but it is what it is.

Comment: Yes, I find it annoying as well, since almost all the data needed is delivered by autocomplete.